# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't read ArcGIS 10.2.2 advanced license

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, visual-studio, arcgis-license-manager

I have an ArcGIS 10.2.2 Advanced License installed. I have Visual Studio 2015 installed. When I open my form I assign.

```c#
public frmMain()
{
    // this must be the first object created
    try
    {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
            init = new AoInitializeClass();
            init.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to obtain license. Application will be shut down.");
        Environment.Exit(1);
   }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

However when I check for the license name, I get a Basic license.

ArcGIS 10.2.2 was installed when I inherited the computer, and I installed Visual Studio 2015 C#.

Would anyone have any idea on why my advanced license would show as a Basic license in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Visual Studio 2015 to read an ArcGIS 10.2.2 Advanced License. Even though I have always used ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense() and things worked.  This time had to use ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind().  I also uninstalled ArcReader which I was reading an Advanced License for.

```
public frmMain()
{
    // this must be the first object created
    try
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
        init = new AoInitializeClass();
        init.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to obtain license. Application will be shut down.");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

to

```
public frmMain()
{
    // this must be the first object created
    try
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
        init = new AoInitializeClass();
        init.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to obtain license. Application will be shut down.");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

ArcObjects .Net SDK for ArcGIS 10.2.x requires Visual Studio 2010 or 2012.  Visual Studio 2015 isn't supported for 10.2.x

See [ArcObjects SDK 10.2.x system requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000) - Scroll to bottom of page for info on *ArcObjects SDK for the Microsoft .NET Framework*.

---

Also:

- ArcObjects for 10.3.x [requires VS 2012 or VS 2013](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/system-requirements/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_134116909B4B4DB888C65AF8FC67CAB9)
- ArcObjects for 10.4.x [requires VS 2013 or VS 2015](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_134116909B4B4DB888C65AF8FC67CAB9)

Comment: Thanks. I figured there would be backward compatibility, especially since I can read the Basic License Just not the Advanced